# Python API and html script: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, python, api

I am trying to create web pages which will accept a login, redirect to a data page all done through API / CRUD in Python and html pages with scripts. All this is for a college assignment.

So, when the user lands on the home page they're redirected to the login-page. In this they enter a Username and Password and click a submit button. All this goes well.

However, on clicking submit, I'm getting the error mentioned in the title. I've validated the JSON in JSONLint.com. The 'return' in the API is a redirect and is received and shows up in the console as an error.

The script of the login page is:

```
    <script>
        function login(){
            // used to create the login
            var userLogin={}
            userLogin.uname=document.getElementById("loginUsername").value
            userLogin.pass=document.getElementById("loginPassword").value
            $.ajax({
                "url":"http://127.0.0.1:5000/processlogin",
                "method":"POST",
                "data":JSON.stringify(userLogin),
                "dataType":"json",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "success":function(result){
                    console.log(result)
                    alert("Logged In");
                },
                "error":function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log("error: " + status + ", message: " + error);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(userLogin))
                    console.warn(xhr.responseText)
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

The API in Python is:

```
@app.route('/processlogin',methods=['GET','POST'])
def process_login():
    # check credentials
    # if bad, redirect to login page again
    #content=request.get_json(force=True)
    #print(content)
    session['username']='got it'
    return redirect('data.html')
```

and the console in the browser shows:

[image: Browser Console]

When I put return 'done' in the Python API, the browser console shows this in the error instead of the HTML code.

Any advice gratefully received.

Seamus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataType` argument in the ajax call means that a JSON return value is expected, but you are returning html.  JQuery tries to deserialise the response and fails.

Ajax isn't really necessary here if you want to redirect the browser to a new page.  Better to submit the form in the usual way and on success redirect to a route that will serve `data.html` as a response.

If the redirect must be performed via Ajax, respond with a redirect to a route that serves `data.html` on the server side.  In the ajax handler, get the redirect url from the response's `location` header, fetch the html and load it.

Comment: Thanks snakecharmerb. I think I have to do it using API. However, you were right about the JSON return. Once I fixed that I could re-direct the page on success